# Update table with stored procedure without null

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I tried to implement procedure which main goal is to store data into new separate table.First I create table which I want to populate with data

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.CustomerReportLogs (
    ID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    CustomerFullName NVARCHAR(100)  NULL,
    LocationName NVARCHAR(100)  NULL,
    Amount decimal (18,2)  NULL,
    Currency NVARCHAR (20) NULL,
    EmployeeId int NULL,
    ValidFrom date NULL,
    ValidTo date  NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_ID_CustomerReportLogs PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
    ID ASC
    ))
    GO
```

So next step is how to populate this table with stored procedure. I order to do this I wrote this lines of code:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.procedure2 (@CustomerId int, @validFrom date, @ValidTo date,@EmployeeID int)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT  CONCAT(c.FirstName, ' ', c.LastName) AS CustomerFullName, lo.Name as LocationName,acd.Amount as Amount,cu.Name as Currency,acc.EmployeeId,@validFrom as ValidFrom,@ValidTo as ValidTo
FROM dbo.Customer as c
INNER JOIN dbo.Account AS acc ON acc.CurrencyId=c.Id
INNER JOIN dbo.AccountDetails AS acd ON acd.AccountId=acc.Id
INNER JOIN dbo.Currency AS cu ON cu.id=acc.CurrencyId
INNER JOIN dbo.Location as lo ON lo.Id=acd.LocationId
INNER JOIN dbo.Employee AS emp ON emp.ID=acc.EmployeeId
WHERE acc.CustomerId=@CustomerId and acd.TransactionDate between @validFrom and @ValidTo and acc.EmployeeId=@EmployeeID
DECLARE @CustomerFullName NVARCHAR(100) 
DECLARE @LocationName NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Amount decimal (18,2) 
DECLARE @Currency NVARCHAR (20)
INSERT INTO dbo.CustomerReportLogs(CustomerFullName,LocationName,Amount,Currency,EmployeeId,ValidFrom,ValidTo)
VALUES (@CustomerFullName,@LocationName,@Amount,@Currency,@EmployeeId,@ValidFrom,@ValidTo)
SELECT @CustomerFullName as CustomerFullName,@LocationName AS LocationName,@Amount AS Amount,@Currency as Currency,
@EmployeeId as EmployeeId,@ValidFrom as ValidFrom ,@ValidTo as ValidTo
END
GO
```

Above line code create stored procudure but now new problem arise namely when I try to execute first whit this command

```
EXEC dbo.procedure2  @CustomerId=8,@validFrom='2019.01.25', @ValidTo='2019.03.01', @EmployeeID=8
```

So this procedure can't update properly dbo.CustomerReportLogs so I got some results with null and some with values.Output you can see on pic below:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

So can anybody help me how to update this table properly not with null

Comment: Well, you don't assign a value for `@CustomerFullName`, `@LocationName`, `@Amount `, or `@Currency` so what else are you expecting..? If you `DECLARE` a variable, and then don't set it a value, of course it's going to `INSERT` the value `NULL`; the default value of a variable is `NULL`... If you want to `INSERT` a non-`NULL` value, set the value of the variable(s).

Comment: CustomerFullName I expect like output, so for that reason I didn't assign value for CustomerFullName.I define input on beginning of procedure CustomerId, validFrom, ValidTo and EmployeeID.Other value I expect like output

Comment: What do you mean you define the input at the beginning? What input? Where is value of `@CustomerName` coming from? All you do is `DECLARE` it and then immediate `INSERT` it; without using a `SET` and `SELECT` to define the value, it won't be given one; you need to use one of those to define the value of said variable(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE  OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.procedure2 (
        @CustomerId INT
        ,@validFrom DATE
        ,@ValidTo DATE
        ,@EmployeeID INT
        )
    AS
    BEGIN
    
        INSERT INTO dbo.CustomerReportLogs (
            CustomerFullName
            ,LocationName
            ,Amount
            ,Currency
            ,EmployeeId
            ,ValidFrom
            ,ValidTo
            )
        OUTPUT INSERTED.[CustomerFullName],INSERTED.[LocationName],INSERTED.[Amount],INSERTED.[Currency],INSERTED.[EmployeeId],INSERTED.[ValidFrom] ,INSERTED.[ValidTo]
    
        SELECT CONCAT (c.FirstName,' ',c.LastName) AS CustomerFullName
            ,lo.Name AS LocationName
            ,acd.Amount AS Amount
            ,cu.Name AS Currency
            ,acc.EmployeeId
            ,@validFrom AS ValidFrom
            ,@ValidTo AS ValidTo
        FROM dbo.Customer AS c
        INNER JOIN dbo.Account AS acc ON acc.CurrencyId = c.Id
        INNER JOIN dbo.AccountDetails AS acd ON acd.AccountId = acc.Id
        INNER JOIN dbo.Currency AS cu ON cu.id = acc.CurrencyId
        INNER JOIN dbo.Location AS lo ON lo.Id = acd.LocationId
        INNER JOIN dbo.Employee AS emp ON emp.ID = acc.EmployeeId
        WHERE acc.CustomerId = @CustomerId
            AND acd.TransactionDate BETWEEN @validFrom
                AND @ValidTo
            AND acc.EmployeeId = @EmployeeID
    
        
    END
```